# Identify the column name of the last occurrence of a value in R data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like below with columns of 1s and 0s. I would like to add a final column that identifies the column name of the final occurrence of 0 per row.

```
have = data.frame(a = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                  b = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0),
                  c = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),
                  d = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1),
                  e = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
> have
   a b c d e
1  1 1 0 1 1
2  0 0 0 0 1
3  1 1 0 1 1
4  1 1 1 1 1
5  0 1 0 0 1
6  0 0 1 0 1
7  1 1 1 0 1
8  1 1 1 1 1
9  1 0 1 0 1
10 0 0 0 1 1
```

I would like the output to look like this where the final column specifies the column name of the last occurring 0 and if one does not exist return NA.

```
> want
   a b c d e last_0
1  1 1 0 1 1      c
2  0 0 0 0 1      d
3  1 1 0 1 1      c
4  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
5  0 1 0 0 1      d
6  0 0 1 0 1      d
7  1 1 1 0 1      d
8  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
9  1 0 1 0 1      d
10 0 0 0 1 1      c
```

I've tried using max.col but it returns the last column name if a zero does not exist. Any other solutions? A dplyr solution is preferred.

```
> have$last_0 = names(have)[max.col(have == 0, ties.method = "last")]
> have
   a b c d e last_0
1  1 1 0 1 1      c
2  0 0 0 0 1      d
3  1 1 0 1 1      c
4  1 1 1 1 1      e
5  0 1 0 0 1      d
6  0 0 1 0 1      d
7  1 1 1 0 1      d
8  1 1 1 1 1      e
9  1 0 1 0 1      d
10 0 0 0 1 1      c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach with `purrr::pmap`:

```
library(dplyr);library(purrr)
have %>% 
   mutate(want = pmap_chr(cur_data(), 
                          ~ tail(c(NA,names(which(c(...)==0))),1)))
   a b c d e want
1  1 1 0 1 1    c
2  0 0 0 0 1    d
3  1 1 0 1 1    c
4  1 1 1 1 1 <NA>
5  0 1 0 0 1    d
6  0 0 1 0 1    d
7  1 1 1 0 1    d
8  1 1 1 1 1 <NA>
9  1 0 1 0 1    d
10 0 0 0 1 1    c
```

`purrr:pmap` is a very useful function because it will work row wise on data and it comes in various flavors so you can control what returns. You can refer to the entire row of data with `c(...)`.

---

If you wanted to apply the procedure to only a subset of columns, you might use `dplyr::select`:

```
have %>% 
    mutate(want = pmap_chr(cur_data() %>% select(a,b,c), 
                           ~ tail(c(NA,names(which(c(...)==0))),1)))
   a b c d e want
1  1 1 0 1 1    c
2  0 0 0 0 1    c
3  1 1 0 1 1    c
4  1 1 1 1 1 <NA>
5  0 1 0 0 1    c
6  0 0 1 0 1    b
7  1 1 1 0 1 <NA>
8  1 1 1 1 1 <NA>
9  1 0 1 0 1    b
10 0 0 0 1 1    c
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Is there a way to select specific columns to apply this to?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `max.col` and then replace those elements that doesn't have any 0 to `NA`

```
have$last_0 <- names(have)[(NA^!rowSums(have == 0)) * max.col(have == 0, 'last')]
```

-output

```
have
   a b c d e last_0
1  1 1 0 1 1      c
2  0 0 0 0 1      d
3  1 1 0 1 1      c
4  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
5  0 1 0 0 1      d
6  0 0 1 0 1      d
7  1 1 1 0 1      d
8  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
9  1 0 1 0 1      d
10 0 0 0 1 1      c
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach:

```
library(dplyr)

have %>%
  purrr::pmap_dfr(\(...) tibble(...,
                                last_0 = which(c(...) == 0) %>%
                                  names %>%
                                  last))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
       a     b     c     d     e last_0
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     1     1     0     1     1 c
 2     0     0     0     0     1 d
 3     1     1     0     1     1 c
 4     1     1     1     1     1 NA
 5     0     1     0     0     1 d
 6     0     0     1     0     1 d
 7     1     1     1     0     1 d
 8     1     1     1     1     1 NA
 9     1     0     1     0     1 d
10     0     0     0     1     1 c
```

Comment: Interesting choice to use base `\()` instead of tidyverse `~`. I like the the use of `dplyr::last`, as that saves some typing over `tail(...,1)` I came up with.

Comment: Thanks! i really like the `pmap_chr(cur_data(),` in your solution. Gotta remember that! Do you know if there is a way to use (...) in a purrr-style ~ ?

Comment: Oh you did! Nevermind then, very cool! :)

Comment: Tidyeval automatically assigns all of the arguments to `...` when you use `~`. You also get `.x`, `.y`, `..1`, `..2`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmax`

```
have$last_0 <- names(have)[replace(do.call(pmax, data.frame((have == 0) * col(have))), rowSums(have) == ncol(have), NA)]
```

---

Another base R option using `max.col`

```
have$last_0 <- replace(names(have)[max.col(1 - have, "last")], rowSums(have) == ncol(have), NA)
```

such that

```
> have
   a b c d e last_0
1  1 1 0 1 1      c
2  0 0 0 0 1      d
3  1 1 0 1 1      c
4  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
5  0 1 0 0 1      d
6  0 0 1 0 1      d
7  1 1 1 0 1      d
8  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
9  1 0 1 0 1      d
10 0 0 0 1 1      c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution, however it may sound a bit verbose. As most of the possible "row_wise" operations had already been suggested, I thought I would try something I had never done before:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

have %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "Last_0", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(desc(val), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  mutate(Last_0 = ifelse(val == 1, "NA", Last_0)) %>%
  select(Last_0) %>%
  bind_cols(have) %>%
  relocate(Last_0, .after = last_col())

# A tibble: 10 x 7
# Groups:   id [10]
      id     a     b     c     d     e Last_0
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1     1     1     1     0     1     1 c     
 2     2     0     0     0     0     1 d     
 3     3     1     1     0     1     1 c     
 4     4     1     1     1     1     1 NA    
 5     5     0     1     0     0     1 d     
 6     6     0     0     1     0     1 d     
 7     7     1     1     1     0     1 d     
 8     8     1     1     1     1     1 NA    
 9     9     1     0     1     0     1 d     
10    10     0     0     0     1     1 c
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the [strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67911256/2884859) used by dear @akrun is fantabulous, but you can simply store the value calculated by you inside a temp variable and replace it like this.   This can be done in dplyr only using `cur_data()`

```
library(dplyr)

have %>% mutate(last_0 = {xx <- names(.)[max.col(cur_data() == 0, ties.method = 'last')];
                          replace(xx, rowSums(cur_data() == 0) == 0, NA)})
#>    a b c d e last_0
#> 1  1 1 0 1 1      c
#> 2  0 0 0 0 1      d
#> 3  1 1 0 1 1      c
#> 4  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
#> 5  0 1 0 0 1      d
#> 6  0 0 1 0 1      d
#> 7  1 1 1 0 1      d
#> 8  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
#> 9  1 0 1 0 1      d
#> 10 0 0 0 1 1      c
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A minimalist **base R** approach (that actually uses nothing but a **grep**-search for the condition):

```
data.frame( have,
     last_0=unlist(apply( have, 1, function(x){
                sol <- grep(0,x);
                if( length(sol > 0 )){
                  colnames(have)[sol[length(sol)]]
                }else{
                  NA } } )) )

   a b c d e last_0
1  1 1 0 1 1      c
2  0 0 0 0 1      d
3  1 1 0 1 1      c
4  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
5  0 1 0 0 1      d
6  0 0 1 0 1      d
7  1 1 1 0 1      d
8  1 1 1 1 1   <NA>
9  1 0 1 0 1      d
10 0 0 0 1 1      c
```